# Basic derivatives

Tags: derivatives, parametric

$x=3 \sin^2(2t)$

$y=3 \cos(2t)$

Equations given for the function $y=f(x) $

What is the derivative of $y=2$ point?

Comment: The derivative of $y = 2$ point?  What's "$y = 2$ point" mean?

Comment: What does '1' mean in title of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, we have:

$$\begin{align}\frac{x}{3}&=\sin^22t \\
&=1-\cos^2 2t \\
&=1-\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)^2\end{align}$$

Now can you take it from here?

Comment: Couldn't solve it :(

Comment: differentiate both sides wrt $x$.